# How do I download an encrypted s3 object without decryption?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Encryption Keys (SSE-C) to store some files. I want to download them but not decrypt them just yet.  The use case is something like the Game of Thrones finale. I want cable operators to have the data but give them the key in the last second.  But the decrypt headers are mandatory when the file is encrypted.  Maybe I can toggle the mark that the file is encrypted?

Answer (score 4):

For this application, you wouldn't use any variant of SSE.

SSE prevents your content from being stored on S3's internal disks in a form where accidental or deliberate compromise of those physical disks or their raw bytes -- however unlikely -- would expose your content to unauthorized personnel.  That is fundamentally the purpose of all varieties of SSE.  The variants center around how the keys are managed.

> Server-side encryption is about data encryption at rest—that is, Amazon S3 encrypts your data at the object level as it writes it to disks in its data centers and decrypts it for you when you access it.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/serv-side-encryption.html

SSE is decrypted by S3 and transiently re-encrypted using TLS for transmission on the network during the download.  The final result in the client's hands is unencrypted.

For the application described, you would just upload the encrypted content to S3 without S3 being aware of the (external, already-applied) encryption.

If you also used some kind of SSE, that would be unrelated to the external encryption that you would also apply.  Arguably, SSE would be somewhat redundant if the content is already encrypted before upload.

In fact, in the application described, depending on sensitivity and value of the content, each recipient would potentially have different keys and/or a slightly different source file (thus a substantially different encrypted file), so that the source of a leak could be identified by identifying which source variant was compromised.